# Can we mint native token from root account on Smart contract?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, token

After building a chain from [Substrate node template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) there are some initial native token balances in the predefined accounts. Can I mint the native token on a smart contract level using the `root` account possibly using ink! smart contract framework?

Answer (score 1):

To deploy the smart contract on substrate chain you need to integrate contract pallet and then with the help of contract you will be able to deploy the Ink smart contract on substrate chain.
https://substrate-developer-hub.github.io/substrate-how-to-guides/docs/pallet-design/add-contracts-pallet/

Comment: I already added a contract pallet...my question was more of a How do I mint a new native token from the smart contract level?

Comment: You need to write the smart contract and then you can deploy the contract by this pallet.
to build the contract you can follow this reference: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/smart-contracts/build-a-token-contract/

Comment: I do not want to mint a custom token from the smart contract, I want to mint native coin/token from the smart contract.

Comment: Ok for native token you need to do it with the help of balances or assets pallet

Comment: But is it even possible from the smart contract side?

Comment: Not see such mechanism for now